# Calculating age based on a column that has only years in it in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datediff, dateadd

I have a column in my table `Employee` called `BirthYear` which stores only the year of birth and not the entire birthdate. I need to calculate the age of every employee using only the `BirthYear` data in SQL Server. How do I do it?

Comment: Short answer: you can't. There will be an inaccuracy...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your query to compute age

```
select DATEPART(year, getdate()) - BirthYear from Employee
```